# Cannot move View in dialog fragment programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment in my application which contains textViews, ImageViews and a custom View.  I've added TouchEvent to the Custom view. What I tried to do is to move the textViews and Imageviews based on the finger movement on the custom views. I tried to use     setX() and setY(). but that doesn't change their location. so i added a log after setX() and setY(). In the log, the co-ordinates are the new co-ordinates I set but the views didn't move. I could change the texts in TextViews in onTouch event but cannot move them.

Comment: Are these in a RelativeLayout? Change their margins instead of using setX/Y()

Comment: Yes, they are in relativelayout.... will try changing their margins and i'll be back....

Comment: @dharms  I tried changing their margins... but it didn't work......

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried? Did you call `requestLayout()` after changing the margins?